# iTunes connect app bundle taken?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, bundle

I just paid $99 so that I can have the opportunity to upload an app that I have been working on to the iOS app store. However, when I try to upload my app, it says the Bundle ID and name are taken. I have been using that Bundle ID to develop the app with the free account status. Now that I have the paid developer license, in Xcode I was able to switch to the paid Team. Here's an image of me using the Bundle ID in Xcode that iTunes connect isn't letting me use: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1mSr.png)

However, when I click the "New App" button in  iTunes connect, and put in that name and Bundle ID, it says that the name and bundle ID are already taken: [Picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mnxxf.png)

Am I doing something wrong? Does it have to do with the XC Wildcard?

Thanks for the help

Comment: So do you have two different Apple developer ID's (a free version and a paid version), or did you upgrade your free account to paid?  If it's the former, I'd suggest simply changing the bundle from "`com.samuel.doubledodge` to `com.mcfadden.doubledodge`.

Comment: Both share the same Apple ID, but in XCode I have two signing certificates with different IDs  (one starts with F3AUD63 and the other starts with B4LTU52). Also, does the package name and the Bundle ID have to match? Thanks